# How to merge String & Int to get in ONE flatMap

Tags: swift, merge, rx-swift, flatmap

```
enum Input { case text(String); case page(Int) }
```

I am managing pagination with keyword search to API method.
Now I either can pass keywords or page number, but not both at same time in Rx.

I have written following code with help of some existing available gist

```
    let start = Observable.merge(reload, loadNext)

    let stringObservable = keyword.asObservable().map { Input.text($0) }
    let intObservable = start.asObservable().map { Input.page($0) }

    let request_call = Observable.of(stringObservable, intObservable).merge()
    let page = request_call
        .flatMap { input in
            Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just($0), api.loadData(page: $0, keyword: "breaking")) { (pageNumber: $0, items: $1) }
                .materialize()
                .filter { $0.isCompleted == false }
        }
        .share()
```

start keep Page Number, & keyword keeps search keywords.

I need to merge both, I did using ENUM & Merge,

Now I have to call API, but showing as Input,

So How can I get both values in one flatMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `Input` enum and use `combineLatest` instead of merge.

Then `request_call` will be an `Observable<(String, Int)>` and you can use the two values in the `loadData` function.

```
let start = Observable.merge(reload, loadNext)

let stringObservable = keyword.asObservable()
let intObservable = start.asObservable()

let request_call = Observable.combineLatest(stringObservable, intObservable)
let page = request_call
    .flatMap { text, page in
        Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(page), api.loadData(page: page, keyword: text)) { (pageNumber: $0, items: $1) }
            .materialize()
            .filter { $0.isCompleted == false }
    }
    .share()
```

Comment: here keyword is 

    let keyword: Observable<String>

and combine latest bring Observable, should I change it to simple String?\

Comment: No keep it an Observable<String>

Comment: It worked. But it never triggered, as I am passing keywords from UI and which is has no INIT method.